# HTTP params entries sharing the same key

Tags: javascript, http, meteor

This Meteor server code uses HTTP 1.1.7 to make a POST request to match what I did using java but I can not figure out how to include more than one entry into the request params which have the same key.

```
//in java 'working'
HttpParams javaParams = new HttpParams();
javaParams.add('food','milk')
javaParams.add('food', 'water')
javaParams.add('food', 'ice')

javaParams.encodeParameters("UTF-8");


//in javascript 'not working'
let headerObject {
  "Content-Type"   : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
  'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5'
   and others
}
const response = HTTP.call('POST', myUrl, {
  timeout: 30000,
  headers: headerObject,
  params: {
    'food': 'milk',
    'food': 'water',
    'food': 'ice'
  }
});

//also tried these but server returned status code 500
food: ['milk', 'water', 'ice']
'food[]': ['milk', 'water', 'ice']
```

How can it this be done? Thanks

Comment: In JavaScript, duplicate keys in object will simply resolve to the last key/value pair so, 

`params: {
    'food': 'milk',
    'food': 'water',
    'food': 'ice'
  }`

Is same as `params: { 'food': 'ice' }` .

If you have a stacktrace of the server error that might help find the root cause.

This might not be useful but try to use double quotes around all your `keys` and `string` values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript, just use an array:

```
const response = HTTP.call('POST', myUrl, {
  timeout: 30000,
  headers: headerObject,
  params: {
    food: ['milk', 'water', 'ice']
  }
});
```

However, different languages on the server side use different mechanisms to handle parameter arrays. While Java should work with the above code, PHP for example needs the parameter name to contain square brackets, so the call would need to be

```
const response = HTTP.call('POST', myUrl, {
  timeout: 30000,
  headers: headerObject,
  params: {
    'food[]': ['milk', 'water', 'ice']
  }
});
```

In the current case, the server side seems to expect each entry in a separate line of the request content as key=value pairs which each key being 'food'. Regrettably, this cannot be done with an JavaScript array nor with a JavaScript object.

To circumvent this problem, we use `data` instead of `params`. This prevents HTTP.call() from creating `data` from the given `params`. It only requires us to handle concatenation of the parameters ourself:

```
const response = HTTP.call('POST', myUrl, {
  timeout: 30000,
  headers: headerObject,
  data: "food=milk\nfood=water\nfood=ice"
});
```

Comment: @joachim's answer seems to be correct to me. Post some log/stacktrace to help resolve the issue.

Comment: @FredJ. Then I think the problem is on the server side. What language do you use?

Comment: @JoachimSchirrmacher `'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5'` updated the post. thx

Comment: @JoachimSchirrmacher Ops, I got what you mean. Not sure what language the remote server uses. I'll give 'food[]' a try. But how do you add this property to params if params is defined earlier and its variable used in the request. i.e. `params.food[] or params['food[]']` gives a node js error

Comment: @JoachimSchirrmacher Also tried `'food[]': ['milk', 'water', 'ice']` for no avail.

Comment: We can try to send parameter data directly and so bypass the JavaScript array: Use `data` instead of `params` and use the string `"food=milk\nfood=water\nfood=ice"` as it's value. This is more like what I expect the Java MultiMap to send.